# Proper get_post blog php - safest way

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, get

What is the proper, safe way to cull blog posts? I'm just being cautious before I code it on my ecommerce site.

On my personal site I've found this to work just fine.

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => 12,
  'offset'      => 1
);
$latest_post = get_posts( $args ); ?>
<?php foreach( $latest_post as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 waypoint_card">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">
        <div class="waypoint_img" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"></div>
        <div class="waypoint_content">
            <h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I end up doubling this $args array so I can separate the first post from the rest (offset 1). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's legit,  if your purpose is to get the first 12 posts minus the first.